# how to do update with new value when conflict occures

Tags: stored-procedures, postgresql-9.5, stored-functions

`create table new(id serial pk ,name varchar (10),age int)`

`id` is autogenerated.

```
insert into new (id,name,age)values(1,' xyz ',21)on conflict(id) do update set name=new_name,age=new_age
```

when the `id` is already available it should `update` the row  by new values using primary key id. when I am first time inserting data I am not passing `id` because its serial type it will auto generate. In this case can I send `id` as `null` because when I am trying to update that time `id` field is required.

Answer (score 1):

From the question it's clear that the code you have given is not the exact code you have. Since you insert without an `id` being passed, as you have described, presumably your actual code looks like this:

```
insert into yourtable(name, age)
values(' xyz ', 21)
on conflict(id) do
update set name='new_name',age='new_age';
```

Since you do not pass an `id`, you will never have a `conflict`, therefore everything will be inserted. In order to handle the `conflict`, you need to be aware of the `id` and do something like this:

```
insert into yourtable(id, name, age)
values(1, ' xyz ', 21)
on conflict(id) do
update set name='new_name',age='new_age';
```

It's clear that you do not necessarily know what the id of the record is, but this is an algorithmic problem. You will need to find out what the `id` is.

Please look at https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/

It has an example:

```
INSERT INTO customers (name, email)
VALUES('Microsoft','hotline@microsoft.com') 
ON CONFLICT (name) 
DO 
   UPDATE SET email = EXCLUDED.email || ';' || customers.email;
```

The table is defined as

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customers;

CREATE TABLE customers (
    customer_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR UNIQUE,
    email VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    active bool NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE
);
```

Please note that `name` is `unique`, so, if the `insert` tries to add a record with a `name` which already exists, then the command is in `conflict` with that record and that will be updated. If you do not provide an `id`, then your command will not have any conflicts and instead of updating, it will `insert` all records.